# VB.NET Create FOREIGN KEY in existing table in Access using SQL?

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I've been having issues with creating relationships programatically in VB.NET for a piece of coursework. I keep getting the error of "Relationship must be on the same number of fields with the same data types." despite the fact that it is an AUTOINCREMENT into a NUMBER. 
Here is the code which i am using, bearing in mind that it creates the table just fine. Any help will be much appreciated.

CODE:

```
    Dim con As OleDbConnection

    Dim command As OleDbCommand

    Dim cat As New Catalog
    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("C:\Users.......\TEST.accdb") = False Then
        Dim str(3) As String
        cat.Create("Provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;Data Source = C:\Users........\TEST.accdb;jet oledb:engine type=5")
        cat = Nothing
        con = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source =C:\Users.......TEST.accdb")
        con.Open()
        str(0) = "CREATE TABLE [tbl_Student] ([StudentID] AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, [CourseID] NUMBER)"
        str(1) = "CREATE TABLE [tbl_Course] ([CourseID] AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)"
        For i = 0 To 1
            command = New OleDbCommand(str(i), con)
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
        con.Close()

        con = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source =C:\Users........TEST.accdb")
        con.Open()
        Try
            str(3) = "ALTER TABLE [tbl_Student] ADD FOREIGN KEY (CourseID) REFERENCES tbl_Course(CourseID)"
            command = New OleDbCommand(str(3), con)
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ErrorToString)
        End Try
        con.Close()
    End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NUMBER` isn't a defined data type for `CREATE TABLE` in Access. I'm surprised it works at all.

Use `LONG` instead.

See [Microsoft Access Data Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714540%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (column "Data type (CREATETABLE)")

Comment: `NUMBER` Is a synonym for `FLOAT`, that is why it works in the create table

Comment: Thanks so much, to be honest I was also suprised that NUMBER worked. That really does explain a lot.
Thanks so much! :D